# Nested ordered lists with different start counter

Tags: html, css

I use Nested counter to create a html ordered list.

This is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Katalhama/YpgfF/

I expect this output

```
0. zero
  0.1 zero.one
1. one
  1.1. one.one
  1.2. one.two
  1.3. one.three
2. two
  2.1 two.one
  2.2 two.two
    2.2.1 two.two.one
    2.2.2 two.two.two
3. three
```

But instead I got this:

```
0. zero
  0.0 zero.one
1. one
  1.0 one.one
  1.1 one.two
  1.2 one.three
2. two
  2.0 two.one
  2.1 two.two
    2.1.0 two.two.one
    2.2.1 two.two.two
3. three
```

I want to start with a 0 index, but i wanna sublists index start at 1. My only thought is using two counters, but i'm not familiar with advanced CSS yet and i don't know howw to manage them :(

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code. The first is very serious. The HTML code is in fact invalid. The `ol` can only contains `li` elements as direct children. But you added `ol` elements as direct children of `ol`. You have to wrap the `ol` elements inside the `li` elements. The second problem is the problem you asked for. To achieve what you want, we can set the `counter-reset` differently for the outermost `ol` and others `ol`:

**HTML**:

```
 <ol id='list'>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two  
   <ol>
    <li>two.one</li>
    <li>two.two</li>
    <li>two.three</li>
   </ol>
  </li>
  <li>three</li>  
  <li>four 
   <ol>
    <li>four.one</li>
    <li>four.two
        <ol>
          <li>four.two.one</li>
          <li>four.two.two</li>
        </ol>
    </li>          
   </ol>
  </li>
  <li>five</li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**:

```
#list { 
  counter-reset: item -1;
}
ol {
  counter-reset: item; 
  padding-left: 10px;  
}
LI { display: block }
LI:before { 
  content: counters(item, ".") " "; 
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

### [Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/YpgfF/2/)

Without using an `id` for the outermost `ol`, you can do something like this:

```
ol { 
  counter-reset: item -1;
}
ol ol {
  counter-reset: item; 
  padding-left: 10px;  
}
LI { display: block }
LI:before { 
  content: counters(item, ".") " "; 
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

### [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/YpgfF/3/)

Here is another approach:

```
ol { 
  counter-reset: item -1;
}
LI { display: block }
LI:before { 
  content: counters(item, ".") " "; 
  counter-increment: item;
}
ol ol li:first-child:before {
  counter-increment: item 2;
}
```

### [Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/YpgfF/4/)

Comment: Thaks a lot! As what i comment at the previous answer, i add ol children element to an other ol cause of typing code instead of paste it from my original file :P 
That answer was very helpul! Now i can understand how the counters work :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the correct numbers for the example on JS Fiddle, change the counter-reset to item 0;

CSS

```
OL {
    counter-reset: item 0;
    padding-left: 10p;
}

LI { 
    display: block
}

LI:before { 
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
    counter-increment: item;
}
```

And your OL's need to be inside your LIs, you can't have an OL inside an OL

HTML:

```
<body>
    <ol>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two
            <ol>
                <li>two.one</li>
                <li>two.two</li>
                <li>two.three</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>three
            <ol>
                <li>three.one</li>
                <li>three.two
                    <ol>
                        <li>three.two.one</li>
                        <li>three.two.two</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>four</li>
    </ol>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

No no your HTML (in the fiddle) is broken. As you mentioned in the title your `<ol>`'s should be **nested**, so that means **inside** other li's, like this

```
<ol>
  <li>Two
    <ol>
      <li>Two.one</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

At the moment your ol's are direct children of your other ol's. Ol's may only have li's as children (or script tags). So at the moment you have this.

```
<ol>
   <li>Two</li>
   <ol>
      <li>Two.one</li>
   </ol>
</ol>
```

When you've changed it to the first codeblock in this answer, you can apply different CSS for nested li's, like this:

```
ol { counter-reset: item -1 }
ol li ol  { counter-reset: item 0 }
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/YpgfF/1/

Comment: check your output in Fiddel.. OP want 0 zer, 1 one but in your fiddel its 0 one...

Comment: Thank you a lot! In my original code i have done it well (nest ol), but wat i needed was ol li ol  { counter-reset: item 0 }. 
Mistake typing the code instead of paste it.

Comment: I provided exactly the solution OP asked for. Read the samples he posted.

Answer (score 0):

By editing Tyblitz **HTML structure**..which was not showing proper result.

```
<body>
 <ol>
  <li>zero</li>
  <li>one
      <ol>
       <li>one.one</li>
       <li>one.two</li>
       <li>one.three</li>
      </ol>
  </li>
  <li>two
      <ol>
       <li>two.one</li>
       <li>two.two
            <ol>
             <li>two.two.one</li>
             <li>two.two.two</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
       </ol>
     </li>
  <li>three</li>
  </ol>
 </body>
```

**CSS**

```
OL { counter-reset: item -1; padding-left: 10px;  }
ol li ol { counter-reset: item 0; }
LI { display: block }
LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```

### [JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/Gagan_Gami/YpgfF/5/)